# detect Card in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

anyone can help me. i build system registration using I/C Card. i also have sdk reader and can read data in i/c card. but my problem now, is how to read i/c card without click any button. user just insert i/c card and system read card and save in database(without user interaction)

i'm using vb 2008 and database sql.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either a FileSystemWatcher to monitor that location or run a timer event that constantly checks for the card's presence and does nothing until it returns a true result